# Is it possible to alter the INPUT packet before it reaches application in libnetfilter_queue

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, netfilter

I want to make some changes in the packets containing specific string. I QUEUE the packets, using iptables match string.
 I tried this but the packet keeps on looping and does not reach the application, it only works when old and new strings are exactly same:

```
static int callBack(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg,struct nfq_data *nfa, void *data)
{
int len=0,id=0;
char *pktData;
string pktString;
struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *pktHeader;
pktHeader = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfa);
if (pktHeader) 
{
    id = ntohl(pktHeader->packet_id);
}
len = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &pktData);
if(len) 
{
    int pos;
    pktString.assign(pktData,len);
    pos=pktString.find("oldstring",0);
    if(pos>0)
    {
        pktString.replace(pos,9,"newstring");
        unsigned char* newPktData=(unsigned char*)pktString.c_str();
        len=pktString.size();
        return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT,len,newPktData);
    }
}   
return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
}
```

The iptable rule used is:

```
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j QUEUE ! -f -m string --to 350 --string "testing" --algo bm
```

Comment: Lean about : Man-in-the-middle attack

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack

Comment: http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-03/bh-us-03-ornaghi-valleri.pdf

Comment: I am doing it on my own machine!